# Error in Django Get request that dosen't make sense

Tags: python, jquery, django, get, request

I have a basic Django app right now which allows users to add items to a database. When the product is added, the list of items should update when a new item is added via the form, and display that Product and all the other Products already in the database. Here is the code I have so far:

This is the `views.py` file with my current implementation of the method that should get the products at the bottom:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from products.models import Product
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

@csrf_exempt
def createProduct(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        description = request.POST.get('description')
        price = request.POST.get('price')

        newProduct = Product(
            name = name,
            description = description,
            price = price
        )

        newProduct.save()

        return HttpResponse('')


def viewProduct(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        ProductList = Product.objects.all()
        products=[]
        for Product in ProductList:
            products.append({"name": Product.name, "description": Product.description, "price": Product.price})
    return JsonResponse(products)
```

The `index.html` page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div>
  <h2 id="title">Create product</h2>
  <input id="name">Name</input>
  <br>
  <input id="description">Description</input>
  <br>
  <input id="price">Price</input>
  <br>
  <button id="add-product">ADD PRODUCT</button>
  </div>

  <div id="productList">
  </div>
</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  document.getElementById('add-product').onclick =  function(){
    sendData();
    getData();
  }
function sendData(){
  var order = {
  name: document.getElementById('name').value,
  description: document.getElementById('description').value,
  price: document.getElementById('price').value
 };

 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'create/product',
  data: order,
  success: function(newProduct){
    console.log("success"),
    $('#name').val(""),
    $('#description').val(""),
    $('#price').val("")
  }
 });
};

function getData(){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'view/product',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data){
      $.each(data.Product, function(index, element){
        $('body').append($('productList', {
          text: element.name
        }));
      });
    }
  });


}

</script>

</html>
```

And the `urls.py` file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from products import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index),
    path('create/product', views.createProduct),
    path('view/product', views.viewProduct)
]
```

So far, adding a product in is fine and causes no issues. However, after writing the `getData()` method and including it, this part dosen't work and returns the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\install\Documents\tutorial\products\views.py", line 29, in viewProduct 
ProductList = Product.objects.all() 
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Product' referenced before assignment
```

I'm confused by this error as I'm not assigning Product anywhere else in this file so not sure why it's returning this error. When I do this same assignment in the Shell, it doesn't have a problem with it and returns all the objects. Can someone help me resolve this? Thanks.

Comment: Here: `for Product in ProductList:` Don't use the variable names that clash with class/method names. That's why you should follow PEP8 and name your variables in lowercase (i.e. `for product in product_list`).

Comment: @Selcuk changed it to your advice, still returns the same 'local variable referenced before assignment error'

Comment: Did you restart your server?

Comment: Yes, restarted a few times

Comment: Not sure what went wrong as the answer you've accepted is exactly the same as my comment. Glad that you resolved it though :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
def viewProduct(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        ProductList = Product.objects.all()
        products=[]
        for Product in ProductList: # <= This is where cause the problem
            products.append({"name": Product.name, "description": Product.description, "price": Product.price})
    return JsonResponse(products)
```

You have to change `for Product in ProductList` to Something else like `for _Product in ProductList`

Try this one:

```
def viewProduct(request):
        if request.method == 'GET':
            ProductList = Product.objects.all()
            products=[]
            for prod in ProductList:
                products.append({"name": prod.name, "description": prod.description, "price": prod.price})
        return JsonResponse(products)
```